# How to make bot grab perma server invite link

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm working on a bot project that has invite feature, currently I'm having trouble with this command that allow bot to grab server perma invite link (that made by owner/admin) and send the invite link into channel where the command is executed or send the link into user dm after they do the command

Here's my code that I used

and here's the result I got https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkoV8.png

```
const db = require('quick.db');

module.exports = {
    config: {
        name: "addpermaserverinvite",
        category: "misc",
        description: "Get the permanent invite link of your server!",
        accessableby: ["moderators", "admins", "owner"],
        usage: "p!addpermaserverinvite",
        aliases: ["permaserverinvite"],
    }}[enter image description here][1]

    module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
        let invite = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('ORANGE')
            .setTitle('Here is your permanent invite link!')
            .setDescription(`${message.guild.name}'s permanent invite link is: ${message.guild.invite}`)
            .setFooter('PhoeniX Bot Invite Link')
            .setTimestamp()
        message.channel.send(invite)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can filter invites with option `maxAge` which is time expiration option and `maxUses` as how many uses should be. If you want to filter it by infinite expiration time, you can filter it as `maxAge: 0`.

For fetching invites, you should have "MANAGE_SERVERS" at least.

```js
    let invites = await message.guild.invites.fetch()
    let infiniteInvite = invites.filter(invite => invite.maxAge === 0 && invite.maxUses === 0).first()
    if(infiniteInvite){
        message.channel.send({embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setDescription(`Your invite link for server **${message.guild.name}**: [Go!](https://discord.gg/${infiniteInvite.code})`)]})
    }
```

[image: example of getting infinite invite on server]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is only 1 invite created by the owner, you can use the below code. If there is more than one, this will not work

```js
...
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    const owwerId = message.guild.ownerId
    const invite = await message.guild.invites.fetch().then(invites => invites.find(inv => inv.inviterId === owwerId))
    const inviteEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('ORANGE')
        .setTitle('Here is your permanent invite link!')
        .setDescription(`${message.guild.name}'s permanent invite link is: https://discord.gg/invite/${invite.code}`)
        .setFooter('PhoeniX Bot Invite Link')
        .setTimestamp()

// if using discord v12
    message.channel.send(inviteEmbed)

    // to DM it
    message.author.send(inviteEmbed)

// if using discord v13
    message.channel.send({
        embeds: [inviteEmbed]
    })

    // to DM it
    message.author.send({
        embeds: [inviteEmbed]
    })
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to make the one that for example getting random server invite link we inside

Comment: Not sure what you mean can you clarify

Comment: so let's say the bot is in server A, and someone from server A try to get invite link by doing the command so they can send it to someone on server B

Comment: The code I posted will pull an invite code from server A, assuming that the owner of that server has only created 1 invite code, If there are multiple invite codes, then the `fetch()` will need to be filtered by `channelId`